# Android- animateCamera with CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition does NOT zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an onClusterItemClickListener. I want the google map (v2) to animate to that position so I use CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition.

**Problem:** google maps animates to the target LatLng but does not zoom, tilt, etc.
I troubleshooted with GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() and it seems that after the animation to the position onCancel() is always called.

Here is my code

```
...<some code before>
@Override
public boolean onClusterItemClick(OffersMarker item) {
   final LatLng markerLocation = item.getPosition();
   final OffersMarker i = item;
   final CameraPosition MARKER_POS = new CameraPosition.Builder()
      .target(markerLocation)
      .zoom(22)
      .bearing(0)
      .tilt(25)
      .build();

   gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(MARKER_POS));
}
```

This code only animates to target with no zoom or tilt.

Here is the version two with troubleshooting

```
  @Override
public boolean onClusterItemClick(OffersMarker item) {
   final LatLng markerLocation = item.getPosition();
   final OffersMarker i = item;
   final CameraPosition MARKER_POS = new CameraPosition.Builder()
      .target(markerLocation)
      .zoom(22)
      .bearing(0)
      .tilt(25)
      .build();

   changeCamera(gmap, CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(MARKER_POS), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("CAM_MOVE", "Finished animate camera");
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancel() {
             Log.d("CAM_MOVE", "Canceled animate camera");
       }
   });
}
```

Here is change camera method

```
private void changeCamera(GoogleMap map, CameraUpdate cameraUpdate, GoogleMap.CancelableCallback cancelableCallback) {
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, cancelableCallback);
}
```

onCancel() is allways called by unknown source.

I am not sure if those are connected (onCancel() being called and zoom not working) but It might as well be.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use "CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom" something like this                                                                          CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LATLONG, CAMERA_ZOOM);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(update);

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the result is the same, no zoom.

Comment: I thought it strange that it should work but look at this link. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: Yes the GMap.movecamera does initate zoom. Problem is that move does not animate. I need smooth animation.

Comment: I undesrtand your point could you show more code? Complete class please.

Comment: It weird. When I use the same method you suggested in a completle different method (current location button onClick method) it all works. But inside a onClusterItemClick()  the zoom does not work.
This suggests that the problem is not the method but the clicklistener running on different thread and being interupted at some point.

Comment: Do you try something like googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(MARKER_POS, 50));

Comment: Thank you Erik for help! I figured it out. Will post an awnser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the solution was hiding in the [click listener returning false](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java#L346-L353) and thus the default method went into action.

Solutions: return true after the onClick code.

Example

```
 private void addClusterItemClickListener(GoogleMap map, ClusterManager cM){
    final GoogleMap gmapI = map;
    cM.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<OffersMarker>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(OffersMarker item) {
            Log.d("CAM_MOVE", "Clicked on marker");
            final LatLng markerLocation = item.getPosition();
            final OffersMarker i = item;
            if (markerLocation != null) {
                //Log.d("GEO_CODE_CRASH", "Latitude: " + markerLocation.latitude + " | " + "Longitude: " + markerLocation.longitude);
                //Log.d("CAM_MOVE", "Moving on with placeSelectHandler");
                placeSelectedHandler(markerLocation.latitude, markerLocation.longitude);
                buildingFragment.setNrOfOffersOnToolber(i.getNrOfOffers());
                getServerResponseAndPopulateBuildingPage(adr,markerLocation);

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLocation, ZOOM_LEVEL_BUILDING);
                gmap.animateCamera(update);

            }
            return true; //<------- THIS NEEDS TO BE TRUE
        }
    });
}
```