# Force animateCamera to complete animation

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to force the camera to animate to a zoom level and coordinate that describes as precisely as possible the area occupied by a list of `LatLng` coordinates.

So far, I have the following:

```
private void focusListOfCoords(Collection<LatLng> coords) {
  LatLngBounds.Builder coordsBoundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
  for (LatLng coord : coords) {
    coordsBoundsBuilder.include(coord);
  }
  LatLngBounds coordsBounds = coordsBoundsBuilder.build();
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(coordsBounds, 50);
  mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

The code above, when zoomed all the way out on the whole world simply pans the view slightly to center on the center point of the bounds. It does not zoom in.

If I replace `mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)` with `mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)`, the projection changes the zoom level (too far in every case, but that's beside the point) and centers as expected.

After trying to troubleshoot this, I noticed that if I implement the `CancelableCallback` for the `animateCamera` method, I can see that the animation is being cancelled.

Is there a way to force the animation to finish? If not, how can I hunt down the cause of the animation being cancelled?

**Edit**: The solution can be found in this question: [Android- animateCamera with CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition does NOT zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908913/android-animatecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newcameraposition-does-not-zoom)

To summarize, my listener method that was calling the animation was returning false which cancelled the animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android- animateCamera with CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition does NOT zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908913/android-animatecamera-with-cameraupdatefactory-newcameraposition-does-not-zoom)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a different approach to your implementation.

One is passing `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom)`  to `animateCamera`. You can specify the zoom level using this. More info on that [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngZoom(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float)).

Or you can build your `CameraView` first before passing it to `animateCamera`. You can check out the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#updating_the_camera_view).

Not really sure why or how it is trigerring `onCancel()`. Maybe something is being fired right after your `animateCamera` call. Try to use the `duration` parameter to alter the speed of the animation and check for changes.

Comment: Your second recommendation is what I'm doing in the snippet I provided. Your first recommendation is simply inlining the factory call and will not change the outcome of the animation. I will try adjusting the duration to see if that helps.

Comment: I found the answer in a different question, thanks for your help.